# Setting up an internal site on EC2

Tags: windows, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

So I've been tasked with installing help docs for an internal tool we use at work. Problem is, getting a dedicated server to host them would be cost prohibitive. I think we can get the webserver up on an AWS EC2, but would there be any way to make it only accessible on our local network?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this a few different ways.  The simplest would be to simply create a security group for the instance that only allows connections from the IP address range of your office.  The more complex solution would be to create a VPC for the instance then connect a VPN between your office and the VPC.

Comment: Okay that's what I thought but I was wondering if there was a better way. Thank you!

Comment: @Amorphous what do you mean by "a better way"? What do these options not accomplish?